# Would like to make sure the lifecycle of React and usage of jQuery datatable with React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatable

guys. I'm a freshman of React and facing some problems now. I'd like to fetch some data from server and show them in a table. I create some features to deal with the loading and error statues. I'd like to render a spinner when the data is loading, an error message if there're some error occured, and the datatable if everything works perfectly.

But here's the issue, in which place should I run the **'ProductRun'** function which initialized the datatable? I tried to put it in ComponentDidMount and componentWillUpdate, but nothing works. I even trie to put it into the render function, but still got nothing. Anybody can show me a way to let it work? Really appreciate!

Here's the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentWrapper from '../../components/Layout/ContentWrapper';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Panel, Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ProductsRun from './products_run';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Spinner from '../../components/widgets/spinner';

class Products extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProducts();
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        if (!nextProps.isloading && !nextProps.error) {
            ProductsRun();
        }
    }

    // Helper function to render an icon for the stock statues of product.

    renderStock(isInStock) {
        if (isInStock) return <span className="label label-success">Stock</span>;
        else return <span className="label label-danger">Out of Stock</span>
    }

    setCurrentProduct(e) {
        const product = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.product);
        this.props.selectProduct(product);
    }


    // Helper function to render all attributes of the products in a table.

    renderProducts() {
        return this.props.products.map((product) => {

            const {
                ProductNum,
                Name,
                Description,
                Item_Cost,
                Reference_Price,
                In_Stock,
                Package,
                Package_Size,
                Product_Size,
                Product_Group,
                Product_Categories,
                Vendor,
                Default_Purchasor
            } = product;

            return (
                <tr key={ProductNum}>
                    <td>{ProductNum}</td>
                    <td>{Name}</td>
                    <td>{Description}</td>
                    <td>{Item_Cost}</td>
                    <td>{Reference_Price}</td>
                    <td className="text-center">
                        {this.renderStock(In_Stock) }
                    </td>
                    <td>{Package}</td>
                    <td>{Package_Size}</td>
                    <td>{Product_Group}</td>
                    <td>{Product_Categories}</td>
                    <td>{Vendor}</td>
                    <td>{Default_Purchasor}</td>
                    <td>
                        <Link to={"products/" + ProductNum}>
                            <i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"
                                onClick={this.setCurrentProduct.bind(this) }
                                data-product={JSON.stringify(product) } />
                        </Link>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        }
        )
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading && !this.props.error) return <ContentWrapper><br/><Spinner/></ContentWrapper>
        else if (this.props.error) return <ContentWrapper><div className="alert alert-danger">{this.props.error.message}</div></ContentWrapper>
        else {
            return (
                <ContentWrapper>
                    <div className="content-heading">Products</div>
                    <Table id="datatable1" responsive striped hover className="b0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={{ minWidth: "40px" }}>
                                    <strong>No.</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <strong>Name</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th style={{ minWidth: "200px" }}>
                                    <strong>Description</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th style={{ minWidth: "75px" }}>
                                    <strong>Item Cost</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th style={{ minWidth: "100px" }}>
                                    <strong>Reference Price</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th className="text-center" style={{ minWidth: "80px" }}>
                                    <strong>In Stock</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <strong>Package</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th style={{ minWidth: "90px" }}>
                                    <strong>Package Size</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <strong>Group</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th style={{ width: "80px" }}>
                                    <strong>Categories</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <strong>Vendor</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th style={{ minWidth: "110px" }}>
                                    <strong>Default Purchasor</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <strong>VIEW</strong>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.renderProducts() }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </ContentWrapper>
            );
        }
    }

}

export default Products;
```

Here's the ProductRun function:

```
export default () => {

    $('#datatable1').dataTable({
        'paging': true, // Table pagination
        'ordering': true, // Column ordering
        'info': true, // Bottom left status text
        // Text translation options
        // Note the required keywords between underscores (e.g _MENU_)
        oLanguage: {
            sSearch: 'Search all columns:',
            sLengthMenu: '_MENU_ records per page',
            info: 'Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_',
            zeroRecords: 'Nothing found - sorry',
            infoEmpty: 'No records available',
            infoFiltered: '(filtered from _MAX_ total records)'
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like:

```
class Products extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setupPlugin();
    }

    componentDidUpdate {
        this.updatePlugin();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.destroyPlugin();
    }

    setupPlugin() {
        $(this.refs.table).dataTable({
            'paging': true, // Table pagination
            'ordering': true, // Column ordering
            'info': true, // Bottom left status text
            // Text translation options
            // Note the required keywords between underscores (e.g _MENU_)
            oLanguage: {
                sSearch: 'Search all columns:',
                sLengthMenu: '_MENU_ records per page',
                info: 'Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_',
                zeroRecords: 'Nothing found - sorry',
                infoEmpty: 'No records available',
                infoFiltered: '(filtered from _MAX_ total records)'
            }
        });
    }

    updatePlugin() {
        // call the plugin method that updates when there is new content
        $(this.refs.table).dataTable("method_name");
    }

    destroyPlugin() {
        // call the plugin method that destroys it
        $(this.refs.table).dataTable("method_name");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table ref="table"></table>
        );
    }
}
```